# How to connect a PHP app to MySQL via pipes?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, named-pipes

I have found glimpses of the fact that it is possible to connect PHP to MySQL via pipes in [their documentation of MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), but I cannot, for the life of me, find anyone explaining what is needed.

The `host` parameter claims:

> When possible, pipes will be used instead of the TCP/IP protocol.

But when is it "possible"? I have my own machine, and I definitely have the necessary privileges to achieve this, I just don't know how. Connecting to the host `localhost` reports "Localhost via UNIX socket" when examining the `host_info`.

Trying to follow one (downvoted) comment from that page, and connecting to host `.`, with `socket` parameter set to `mysql`, causes a `2002` connection error.

How do I tell it to (always) connect via a pipe instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named Pipes only work under Windows.

Also

> > Whenever you specify "localhost" or "localhost:port" as server, the MySQL client library will override this and try to connect to a local socket (named pipe on Windows). If you want to use TCP/IP, use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost". If the MySQL client library tries to connect to the wrong local socket, you should set the correct path as in your PHP configuration and leave the server field blank.

It is not mentioned in the actual PHP documentation, but it should be still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same issue and it required much time to solve this on Windows.
I can establish a named pipe connection with the following code:

```
$connection = new mysqli('.', 'user', 'pass', 'database', null, '\\\\.\\pipe\\name_of_pipe');
```

The server, where I want to connect to, has the following configuration:

```
[mysqld]
skip-networking
enable-named-pipe
socket=name_of_pipe
```

Using `'127.0.0.1'`, `'localhost'` or `NULL` as hostname doesn't work. Also you must specify a path to the named pipe and not just the name of the pipe.
Unfortunately the PHP documentation is a little bit weak here...